# Remove duplicates and substrings from a list of strings

Tags: python, string, list, duplicates, substring

Let's say that I have a list given by:

```py
a = [
    'www.google.com',
    'google.com',
    'tvi.pt',
    'ubs.ch',
    'google.it',
    'www.google.com'
]
```

I want to remove the duplicates and the substrings to keep a list like:

```py
b = [
    'www.google.com',
    'tvi.pt',
    'ubs.ch',
    'google.it'
]
```

Do you know an efficient way to do that?

The goal is to keep the string that is longer, that's why `www.google.com` is preferred over `google.com`.

Comment: wouldn't google.it be removed as well as it is a substring? How do you choose which item is a substring of which element? Every element with 'google' in it is a substring of one another.

Comment: Why `www.google.com` and not `google.com`?

Comment: `set('.'.join(x.split('.')[-2:]) for x in a)` gives `{'tvi.pt', 'google.com', 'google.it', 'ubs.ch'}`. Close enough?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp, this doesn't cover TLDs that has `3` levels, for example.

Comment: Because I have a ocr text as a string. Then I do some regex to get information that I am looking foward. But it can create duplicates if they appear several times written differently because of the ocr

Comment: @CaptainCaveman thank you for your help but google.it is not a substring

Comment: 'google' is not a substring of 'google.it', 'google.com' and 'www.google.com'?

Comment: @Goncalves I think the question is: what is the logic behind choosing `www.google.com` over  `google.com` ? Because it is longer? Because it appears more? Something else?

Comment: IMHO, `substring` is a misused word here. As far as I can see, what OP really means is top level domains.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp, yes, exactly.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Sorry for the missunderstanding ! Yeah I choose `www.google.com` because it is longer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution can be edited to better suit your needs. Edit the functions `get_domain` to better choose the grouping condition* and the `choose_item` function to better choose the best item of the group.

```
from itertools import groupby

a = ['www.google.com', 'google.com', 'tvi.pt', 'ubs.ch', 'google.it', 'www.google.com']

def get_domain(url):
    # Example: 'www.google.com' -> 'google.com'
    return '.'.join(url.split('.')[-2:])

def choose_item(iterable):
    # Ex. input: ['www.google.com', 'google.com',  'www.google.com']
    # Ex. output: 'www.google.com' (longest string)
    return sorted(iterable, key=lambda x: -len(x))[0]

results = []
for domain,grp in groupby(sorted(a, key=get_domain), key=get_domain):
    results.append(choose_item(grp))

print(results)
```

Output:

```
['www.google.com', 'google.it', 'tvi.pt', 'ubs.ch']
```

<sub>*Another answers suggest the tld library.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

If what you are looking for is a list of unique first level domains, given an arbitrary list of URLs, take a look at the [`tld`](https://tld.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) module. It will make things easier for you.

Based on the documentation, here is a snippet that you can adapt for your needs:

```py
from tld import get_fld

urls = [
    'www.google.com',
    'google.com',
    'tvi.pt',
    'ubs.ch',
    'google.it',
    'www.google.com'
]

unique_domains =  list({
    get_fld(url, fix_protocol=True) for url in urls
})
```

The code above will set `unique_domains` with:

```py
['ubs.ch', 'google.it', 'tvi.pt', 'google.com']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the duplicates as follows:

```
f = list(dict.fromkeys(a))
```

this will filter out the duplicates 'www.google.com' but not the substrings. This would need more clarification as Captain Caveman wrote in his comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
def remove_duplicates_and_substrings(input):
output = []
for i in input:
    if i not in output:
        if not any(i in s for s in output):
            output.append(i)
return output
```

It may not be the best approach but does exactly what it you want it to do.
It works by first checking if the string from the input list is not already in the output list.
Then it checks if any part of that is already in one of the output strings. If this is not the case it will add it to the output list.